# Entity mapping issues

Tags: jpa, mapping, entities

I am pretty new to java and data entities and I am getting the, "Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class com.store.Product] and [class com.store.Cart]." error and not sure why (obviously).

My mappings are as follows:

Product.java

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "P_QTY")
private Integer pQty;
@Column(name = "P_PRICE")
private BigDecimal pPrice;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "P_ID")
private String pId;
@Size(max = 10)
@Column(name = "P_NAME")
private String pName;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "P_DESC")
private String pDesc;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pId")
```

Cart.java

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "C_ID")
private String cId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "C_QTY")
private Integer cQty;
@Column(name = "C_PRICE")
private Double cPrice;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@JoinColumn(name = "P_ID", referencedColumnName = "P_ID")
@ManyToOne
private String pId;
```

Any ideas?  Like I said, I'm new to data entities and have done enough reading to confuse myself at this point so I apologize for any and all idiocy on my part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the Product's point of view I think you want to use a Many (products) to one (cart) mapping. Vice versa in cart you want to map one (cart) to many (products).

Comment: Furthermore you want to use cId in product instead of pId in cart. If cart has one variable which stores a pId, how would you put more than one product in the cart?